# APPEND or UPDATE action for updateContext in Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware-orion

I am confused as to what is the correct one. According to the [documentation](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Entity_Creation) you can use both *APPEND* and *UPDATE* in the field *updateAction*.

What is the actual difference? How is this related to registerContext?

Comment: I forgot to add: what I'm trying to do is to create an entity.

Comment: To create an entity definitively you needc to use APPEND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, APPEND/UPDATE has nothing to do wigh registerContext: APPEND/UPDATE are used in updateContext requests, which is a NGSI10 operation, while registerContext is an NGSI9 operation.

The general rule is to use APPEND when you have to create new context element in Orion Context Broker (e.g. a new entiy or a new attribute in an existing entity) and UPDATE when you are updating an existing context element (e.g. a previously created entity/attribute).

Some additional remarks:

- An updateContext using UPDATE in a non-existing context element will result in a "Not found" error response.
- An updateContext using APPEND in a non-existing context element will result in the creation of that element.
- An updateContext using APPEND in a existing context element will be interpreted as a UPDATE (at least in Orion 0.12.0 and before).

**EDIT**: Orion 0.24.0 introduces the [APPEND_STRICT action](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user/append_and_delete/index.html), which is like APPEND but returning an error if the attribute to add already exists.